# Who am I?...Younger and older does not meet

Tags: riddle, pattern

Younger and older does not meet.

But big and small does meet.

Tall and short does not meet.

Breadth does but length never meets...

Who am I?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

hehehe the answer is:

> Lips.  Read the words and you will figure it out
>
> (Your lips touch when you say big and small, and Breath)

Comment: I need it spelled out I still don't get it.

Comment: @user3453281 Your lips touch when you say `big` and `small`, and **Brea**th.

Comment: thank you, I was way off trying to figure out your answer. I was thinking "young people can't kiss old people but small people and big people can kiss for some reason"

Comment: Hm... lips, kissing, old people...sorry I can't relate them yet =D

Answer (score 2):

> The letter B?

"Younger and older" doesn't contain it, "big and small" does, "tall and short" doesn't, "breadth" does at the beginning, "length" doesn't.

Comment: good one ... but that's not the answer.. :)

Comment: "small" doesnt have B

Comment: That's what I thought too

Comment: @RichardLi But "big and small" does!